# How to execute JavaExec multiple times in a single task using Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a task that runs a simple JavaExec.

What I cant seem to get working is the ability to run the JavaExec multiple times while iterating a Filetree object (containing the files) each of while I want to pass into the main JavaExec class one by one. Unfortunately the compiler or code generation tool as it is doesnot accept a directory as an arg so I need to pass the file as an arg per loop. Here's what I have:

```
task generateClasses(type: JavaExec) {
   description = 'Generates Json Classes...'
   classpath configurations.all
   main = "org.apache.gora.compiler.Compiler"
   FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: 'src/main')
   tree.include '**/*.json'
       tree.each {File file ->
       println file
       args = [ "src/main/json/$file.name", "$buildDir/generated-src/src/main/java" ]
   }
```

}

compileJava.source generateClasses.outputs.files, sourceSets.main.java

From the above it works and I get all files listed but the JavaExec is called just the once on the very last file read.

How do I address the above? Please help.

Comment: Obviously breaking the above into separate tasks and runing JavaExec n times would be a solution but this makes the build file too verbose and not flexible (I have to specify path to each file).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How about using the `project.javaexec` method?  See the [API Documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) or the 
[DSL ref](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:javaexec(groovy.lang.Closure)).

```
task generateClasses {
  description = 'Generate Json Classes'
  fileTree(dir: 'src/main', include:'**/*.json').each { file ->
    doLast {
      javaexec {
        classpath configurations.all
        main = 'org.apache.gora.compiler.Compiler'
        args = ["src/main/json/$file.name", "$buildDir/generated-src/src/main/java"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```